# Mercurial: Get non-versioned copy of an earlier version of a file

Tags: version-control, mercurial

How do I get a non-versioned copy of an older version of a file from a mercurial repository?

**Edit:** I have changed somefile.png (binary file) in my local copy. I am looking for a command which will allow me to get an earlier version of somefile.png so that I can compare it with my modified copy (using an image viewer) before I commit changes. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by non-versioned? you can just copy files out of the repo; the whole versioning (meta)data is 'external' to the file ...

Comment: You're right... I've edited the question to explain what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you are looking for is cat

hg cat [OPTION]... FILE...

output the current or given revision of files

```
hg cat -o outputfile.png -r revision somefile.png
```

You can then compare somefile.png with outputfile.png

Answer (score 1):

If you mean: [what is the equivalent of svn export?](http://www.isaacsu.com/wilt/articles/mercurial-hg-equivalent-of-svn-export-), that would be:

```
hg archive ..\project.export
```

See also this [TipsAndTrick section](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Make_a_clean_copy_of_a_source_tree.2C_like_CVS_export)

> Make a clean copy of a source tree, like CVS export

```
hg clone source export
rm -rf export/.hg
```

> or using the archive command

```
cd source
hg archive ../export
```

> The same thing, but for a tagged release:

```
hg clone --noupdate source export-tagged
cd export-tagged
hg update mytag
rm -rf .hg
```

> or using the archive command

```
cd source
hg archive -r mytag ../export-tagged
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a tip on the [hgtip](http://hgtip.com) that might get you most of the way there:

[Merging binary files](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-11-30-merging-binary-files/)

While it specifically talks about merging, the diff stuff should be generic enough to do it outside a merge...

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure I understand the question. You you could just copy it somewhere else using the normal file copy tools of your operating system.

Comment: Please ask questions as comments to the original question. This is not a real answer. Thanks :)

Comment: You need at least 50 Reputation points to leave comments. As I'm new to this site I  don't have them yet, so I couldn't. Thanks for the down-vote anyway.